# Ground truth dataset

Tags: data-request

I need to check the quality of my causality inference algorithm, so i want to check it with a dataset in which the causal relationships are already given. Is there a particular place for me to look at?

Edit :

Example of a dataset :
X1 X2 X3
1.0 2.0 3.0
2.0 3.0 4.0

The columns are the variables . I want to have a dataset like that with given causal relationships between the variables

Comment: Can you clarify your question with examples of data set you already worked with or are looking for.

Comment: @magdmartin added edit